# Stuck with a ValueError, How to solve it?

Tags: python, error-handling

I am doing a assignment and I need to extract text from PDF using PyPDF2 and while trying to do that am getting this error. How to fix this?
can someone help me? thank you in advance.

```
import PyPDF2
textFile = open('foo.txt', 'w')
file = open('foo.pdf','rb')
readpdf = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(file)
print(readpdf.getNumPages())
1
read_pdf = readpdf.getPage(0) 
textFile.write(read_pdf.extractText())

--------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call 
last)
<ipython-input-42-5a892ea3012b> in <module>
----> 1 textFile.write(read_pdf.extractText())

ValueError: I/O operation on closed file.

file.close
textFile.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how you ended up with this error, but this might help:

```py
textFile = open('foo.txt', 'w')
read_pdf = readpdf.getPage(0) 
textFile.write(read_pdf.extractText())
```

Opening the file right before you do something with it seems to work for me, so give it a try and we'll see ;]

Answer (score 0):

using `with open` you dont need to handle the exception and closing file, it handle this by itself

```
import PyPDF2
with open('foo.txt','w') textFile:
    with open('foo.pdf','rb') as file:
        readpdf = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(file)
        print(readpdf.getNumPages())
        read_pdf = readpdf.getPage(0) 
        textFile.write(read_pdf.extractText())
```